# Electron - Make Windows Title bar Looks like Muno Title bar

Tags: javascript, html, electron, titlebar

I want to make the title bar of Windows Looks Like [Muno Title bar](http://munoapp.com)

I tried to use [This title bar](https://www.npmjs.com/package/titlebar)
but it don't show Anything

Please help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

He, I am the developer of Muno. Maybe I can help.

I use browserWindow options:

```
const {width, height} = electron.screen.getPrimaryDisplay().workAreaSize;

let options = {
   show: false,
   frame: false,
   center: !isDev,
   titleBarStyle: 'hidden',
   width: Math.round((width / 100) * 85),
   height: Math.round((height / 100) * 85),
};
```

The other part is just CSS and I used this snippet for the traffic light buttons:
https://codepen.io/atdrago/pen/yezrBR

Hope this helps. What are you making?